# Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 1 columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android app that is trying to load a blob from an SQLite database as a byte array:

```
public byte[] getBytesForId(long id){
    byte[] result = null;
    String sql =  "SELECT _blob FROM test_table WHERE _id=?";
    String[] selection = new String[] { String.valueOf(id) };

    Cursor mCursor = super.DB().rawQuery(sql, selection);

    if ( mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst() ) {               
        if (mCursor.getCount() > 0)
            result = mCursor.getBlob(0);

        if (mCursor != null && !mCursor.isClosed())
            mCursor.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

but I get the following exception:

```
Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 1 columns.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetBlob(Native Method)
at android.database.CursorWindow.getBlob(CursorWindow.java:404)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:45)
at com.test.testapp.model.DbClass.getBytesForId(DbClass.java:218)
at com.test.testapp.TestService.StepThroughBlocks(TestService.java:434)
at com.test.testapp.TestService.checkBlocks(TestService.java:378)
at com.test.testapp.TestService.access$4(TestService.java:357)
at com.test.testapp.TestService$2.run(TestService.java:315)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

surely if I am checking that the cursor has some data first...

```
if ( mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst() ) 
        if (mCursor.getCount() > 0)
            result = mCursor.getBlob(0);
```

...I shouldn't be getting this exception? I added the mCursor.getCount line hoping that might help but I'm still getting the exception. How is this possible?

Comment: How large is your data? Android sqlite adds a `CursorWindow` which has limited space for row data and you can get this exception if the data doesn't fit the window.

Comment: It is a reasonably large amount of data (1-2Mb per row), so I'm guessing that may be the problem. A more helpful exception would have put me on track sooner. Is there any way to get the data off that happily inserted without any errors?!

Comment: The default size for `CursorWindow` is 2MB so it's very likely your blob doesn't fit there. Consider storing your binary data outside the db.